# FluentValidation: How do i put all validation messages at a single location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, fluentvalidation

This is one of my validation class:

```
public class StocksValidator : AbstractValidator<Stocks>
    {
        public StocksValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.SellerId).GreaterThan(1).WithMessage("SellerId should be greater than 1")
                                    .LessThan(100).WithMessage("SellerId should be less than 100");
            RuleFor(x => x.SellerType).GreaterThan(101).WithMessage("SellerType should be greater than 101")
                                    .LessThan(200).WithMessage("SellerType should be less than 200");
            RuleFor(x => x.SourceId).GreaterThan(201).WithMessage("SourceId should be greater than 201")
                                    .LessThan(300).WithMessage("SourceId should be less than 300");
        }
    }
```

I understand that these messages like {field} should be less that {x} should be at a common location and not here. But i don't have a clue how to centralize them?

1. One way could be to create new c# file with all these constant strings. This is fairly simple.
2. Using localization in web api with fluent validation. What are benefits of this. Where do i find its good tutorial?

Comment: It looks like you're using default messages, so all the `WithMessage` can be omitted. As for localization - it depends on your requirements

Comment: yeah i did the same. They have good default error message support. skipping all with message is fine for me now as all i want is consistency b/w message across all the apis.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to change default messages for built-in rule(s), that **will affect all validators**, which contain this rule(s) — follow next steps:

**1**: set up fluent validation with your custom resource provider class at `Startup.cs` or `global.asax.cs`

```
ValidatorOptions.ResourceProviderType = typeof(MyResourceProvider);
```

**2**: override default messages for some validation rules

```
// create MyResourceProvider.resx to auto-generate this class in MyResourceProvider.Designer.cs file (support multiple cultures out of box),
// or create class manually and specify messages in code
public class MyResourceProvider {
   public static string greaterthan_error {
      get { 
          return "{PropertyName} should be greater than {ComparisonValue}, but you entered {PropertyValue}";
      }
   }
   public static string lessthan_error {
      get { 
          return "{PropertyName} should be less than {ComparisonValue}";
      }
   }
}
```

**3 (optional)**: use `WithName()` method to replace default output of property name with more user-friendly

```
RuleFor(x => x.SellerId).GreaterThan(1).WithName("Seller identidier") 
// outputs "Seller identidier should be greater than 1, but you entered 0"
```

More information you can find at [FluentValidation github](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/):

[1. Localization](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/f.-Localization) — here you can find more info about ways to localize messages (like `WithLocalizedMessage` method), and also resource names, that should be used as property names in `MyResourceProvider`.

[2. Built in Validators](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/c.-Built-In-Validators) - here you can find substitution names for all validation rules, that should be used in error message strings.

[3. Messages.resx](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/Resources/Messages.resx) - default resource file with error messages placed here.