# fluentvalidation error message contains c# property name and not client side json property name?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I have a C# WebApi project and i am using FluentValidation.WebApi package for validation of client inputs.

Below is my model class code which has C# property named "IsPremium". This same property has json name "isLuxury" for all the clients.

```
[Serializable, JsonObject, Validator(typeof(ProductValidator))]
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("isLuxury")]
    public bool? IsPremium { get; set; }
}
```

And my validator class looks like:

```
public class ProductValidator : AbstractValidator<Product>
    {
        public ProductValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(product => product.isPremium).NotNull();
        }
    }
```

So for a request like:
http://localhost:52664/api/product

Request body:{
        "isLuxury": ""
}

I get following error:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "product.isPremium": [
      "'is Premium' must not be empty."
    ]
  }
}
```

Fluent here is picking C# property name which makes no sense to the client as it knows it as "isLuxury". How can i force fluent to pick names from json property and not from c# property to give better validations like "'isLuxury' must not be empty."?

If not possible, i will have to rename all my C# properties to have same name as these json exposed to all the clients. Please suggest if you have any other better way to solve this problem.

Comment: You could I think do that by [Overriding the Default Property Name](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/d.-Configuring-a-Validator#overriding-the-default-property-name) to use the Json property name.

Comment: even this solves problem partially, since i get    
"product.isPremium": ["'isLuxury' must not be empty."] - now product.isPremium makes no sense to the end user of api. can i change that too?

Comment: got it, i had to use- OverridePropertyName. thanks for your help.

Comment: -1, I mentioned way to solve your problem [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38755177/571203) to one of your previous questions. Please, read [documentation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/a.-Index) before you ask new question.

Comment: yeah my bad.. didn't read your previous answer properly. will make sure to read the documentation first. thanks for the direction.

Comment: @stuartd: i get same problem despite using override methods. can you please see https://dotnetfiddle.net/C1LRuX and help me when i have nested list within this object?

Comment: @sahil that fiddle doesn't even compile

Comment: yeah it won't. its just for reference. just wanted to share the class definitions. let me know if you are not able to understand that. i have mentioned the classes, request url and kind of "duplicate" response error i get back.

Comment: @sahil I have my own work to do.

Comment: Cool. I would understand this fiddle better. And try to replicate here if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15):

Modify the validator class with the  `OverridePropertyName` method

```
public class ProductValidator : AbstractValidator<Product>
    {
        public ProductValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(product => product.isPremium).NotNull().OverridePropertyName("isLuxury");
        }
    }
```

Referring: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/d.-Configuring-a-Validator#overriding-the-default-property-name

Alternatively you can call the `WithName` method which does a similar thing. If you want to completely rename the property, I'd use the `OverridePropertyName` method.

Comment: Calling `WithName` sufficient, if you call `OverridePropertyName` for same property

Comment: Rather reverse is true. Calling OverridePropertyName sufficient if we want to call WithName for the same property.

Comment: Anyway, there is no need to call both methods, in any situation.

Answer (score 1):

As Sahil said, use the OverridePropertyName method. If you also use it in conjunction with this, it automatically figures out the JSON property name:

```
private string GetJsonPropertyName<T>(string propertyName)
{
    string jsonPropertyName =
        typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.Name == propertyName)
        .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>())
        .Select(jp => jp.PropertyName)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (null == jsonPropertyName)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Type {nameof(T)} does not contain a property named {propertyName}");
    }

    return jsonPropertyName;
}
```

Which is then used like this:

```
RuleFor(product => product.IsPremium)
    .NotNull()
    .OverridePropertyName(
        GetJsonPropertyName<Product>(nameof(Product.IsPremium))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your validator validate JSON object (DTO), you can create an abstract implementation of `AbstractValidator<T>` which contains the JSON property path instead of the C# property path.

```cs
public abstract class JsonAbstractValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    protected JsonAbstractValidator()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnRuleAdded(IValidationRule<T> rule)
    {
        var jsonPropertyPath = GetJsonPropertyPath(rule.Expression);

        rule.PropertyName = jsonPropertyPath;
        SetDisplayName(rule, jsonPropertyPath);

        base.OnRuleAdded(rule);
    }

    private static void SetDisplayName(IValidationRule<T> rule, string name)
    {
        // The SetDisplayName() method is not available in the IValidationRule<T>.
        // A feature request has been submitted on the GitHub of FluentValidation to avoid using reflection:
        // https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/2179
        var setDisplayNameMethod = rule.GetType().GetMethod("SetDisplayName", new[] { typeof(string) }) !;

        setDisplayNameMethod.Invoke(rule, new object[] { name });
    }

    private static string GetJsonPropertyPath(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body;

        if (body is UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
        {
            body = unaryExpression.Operand;
        }

        if (body is not MemberExpression memberExpression)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The argument is not expression to access to a property.", nameof(expression));
        }

        var path = new List<string>();

        while (true)
        {
            if (memberExpression.Member is not PropertyInfo property)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The argument is not expression to access to a property.", nameof(expression));
            }

            path.Add(GetJsonPropertyName(property));

            if (memberExpression.Expression is ParameterExpression)
            {
                break;
            }

            var nextMemberExpression = memberExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;

            if (nextMemberExpression is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The argument is not expression to access to a property.", nameof(expression));
            }

            memberExpression = nextMemberExpression;
        }

        path.Reverse();

        return string.Join('.', path);
    }

    private static string GetJsonPropertyName(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>();

        if (attribute is not null)
        {
            return attribute.Name;
        }

        return property.Name;
    }
}
```

Next, you just have to update your validator to inherit from the `JsonAbstractValidator<T>` class:

```cs
public class ProductValidator : JsonAbstractValidator<Product>
{
    public ProductValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(product => product.IsPremium).NotNull();
    }
}
```

By inheriting with the `JsonAbstractValidator<Product>` you should have the following error message: `"'isLuxury' must not be empty."`

**NOTE:** My `JsonAbstractValidator<T>` class use `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute of the `System.Text.Json` feature.
If you use the `Newtonsoft.Json` implementation, replace the `GetJsonPropertyName()` method with the following implementation:

```cs
private static string GetJsonPropertyName(PropertyInfo property)
{
    var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();

    if (attribute is not null)
    {
        return attribute.PropertyName;
    }

    return property.Name;
}
```